# jmeter imap reverse order search criteria and getting the last value

Tags: regex, email, jmeter, imap, forgot-password

I'm trying to retrieve a OTP email from a imap account (testing using gmail), and the gmail account is a new "test" account with 3 emails, the basic gmail welcome, another gmail email, and the OTP test email with code.

So I can scan a basic account like this, wrote a reg ex to retrieve the OTP code from the email body.  #1 the message list is retrieved oldest to newest, so if IMAP reader is configured for 1 email, it only gets the oldest.

> How do I configure to get the newest?

Basically using a sort key:
search_criteria = '[REVERSE] sort-key' #format for sorting According to RFC5256 these are valid sort-key's:
"ARRIVAL" / "CC" / "DATE" / "FROM" / "SIZE" / "SUBJECT" / "TO"

Basically, this works fine for my simple test scenario, and in a dummy account like this, likely I could use the "Delete messages from Server" feature.

Jmeter formats the email fetch like this:

```
imaps://xxxtestacount22@gmail.com@imap.gmail.com:993/INBOX[-1]
```

The Imap reader element allows for the freeform text input for "FOLDER" = "INBOX", the -1 is retrieve all emails, it's a count #. 
So is there a syntax for this connection object that can be used to send through something like    INBOX'[REVERSE] DATE' ?

Is there any other tricks or work arounds for this issue? 
Maybe I'll just used throw away accounts for testing, and it won't matter, the delete trick will do.

Followed this wiki: 
http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-create-jmeter-script-check-email-during-registration-and-grab-confirmation-url

This was relatively helpful in determining the viability of the approach.  (NOTE: I couldn't get POP3 to work on gmail, so I used the imap feature).

I retrieve the OTP value using the reg ex, how does one get the last match of series? In jmeter a positive number N means to match the Nth occurrence, is 999,999 valid to always find the last occurrence, if I'm unable to the imap email reader to come in REVERSE "newest" order?

To recap, my options are in order IMHO of preference:

1> retrieve imap in REVERSE "newest" order ? how to do with OOTB jmeter 
2> retrieve the last RegEx extractor match reading in default oldest to newest mode 
3> opinions on using delete option to keep the list small. 
4> ?other tricks?

thanks 
ken

Answer (score 0):

The `SORT` extension is not supported by GMail, and [they have no plans to support it in future](http://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/imapext/current/msg04897.html).

One possible way of solving this would be to do something like `SEARCH FROM your-sender@example.org` and using the highest message number from the resulting set (both higher sequence numbers and higher UIDs imply that the message was added to that mailbox "more recently" than anything else; this has obvious drawbacks when one considers what happens when user moves messages between folders, but it's as good as you can have it here).